# Converting strings into float and integers (if is necessary) in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, integer

I've to call an API that sometimes returns me numerical values in string format, `"288"` instead of `288`, or `"0.1523"` instead of `0.1513`. Some other times, I get the proper numerical value, `39`.

How can I make the function to format it to the proper value? This means:

- If I get `"288"` convert it to an integer: `288`.
- If I get `"0.323"` convert it to a float: `0.323`.
- If I get `288` leave it as it is (its an integer already).
- If I get `0.323` leave as it is (its a float already).

This is my try. The thing is that this also converts me all the floats into integers, and I don't want this. Can someone give me hand?

```
def parse_value(value):
    try:
       value = int(value)
    except ValueError:
        try:
            value = float(value)
        except ValueError:
            pass
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you making a distinction between float and int? For most usecases `float(value)` is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def parse_value(value):
    try:
       print(type(value))
       if type(value) is float:
           print(value)
       elif type(value) is int:
           print(value)
       elif type(value) is str:
           value = float(value)
           print(value)

    except ValueError:
        try:
           print(value)
        except ValueError:
            pass
```

Answer (score 1):

Use following:

```
def convert(self, value)
    a=value
    b=float(a)
    if(b==int(b)):b=int(b) 
    
    print(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you?

```
def parse_value(value):
    f = float(value)
    r = f if f != int(f) else int(f)
    return r
```